# How can I style the arrow of react-multi-select-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select

I'm looking to customize the downward arrow icon in the react multi-select component. In the documentation, there is an attribute `ArrowRenderer` which takes reactNode as a value.

How to configure this to customize the styles?
Dropdown looks like:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: put a demo here(ex: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) should be easier for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

Put your react node in div tag with specific class(Name) and then  access that class by css selectors.

```
<MultiSelect
 arrowRenderer={()=> 
   <div className="custom-arrow" >
     <CustomArrowComponent />
   </div>
  }
/>
```